# symfony 4 - "Property App\\Model\\BaseCar::$model does not exist"

Tags: symfony4

Hi I'm trying to extend an entity from a model in symfony. here is my model,

```
<?php

namespace App\Model;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Swagger\Annotations as SWG;




class BaseCar  
{
     /**
     * @var int
     * @SWG\Property(description="The unique identifier of the car.")
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @SWG\Property(type="string", maxLength=255)
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @SWG\Property(type="string", maxLength=255)
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $code;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Model",cascade={"refresh","merge"}, inversedBy="cars")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    protected $model;

    /**
     * @SWG\Property(type="string", maxLength=255)
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $year;

    /**
     * @SWG\Property(type="string", maxLength=255)
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $type;

    /**
     * @SWG\Property(type="string", maxLength=255)
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $body_type;

    /**
     * @SWG\Property(type="string", maxLength=255)
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $engine_power;

    /**
     * @SWG\Property(type="string", maxLength=255)
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $fuel;

    /**
     * @SWG\Property(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $doors;

    /**
     * @SWG\Property(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $seats;

    /**
     * @SWG\Property(type="string", maxLength=255)
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $transmission;

    /**
     * @SWG\Property(type="string", maxLength=255)
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $weigth;

    /**
     * @SWG\Property(type="string", maxLength=255)
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $engine_position;

    /**
     * @SWG\Property(type="string", maxLength=255)
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $engine_type;

    /**
     * @SWG\Property(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $cylinders;

    /**
     * @SWG\Property(type="string", maxLength=255)
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $engine_capacity;

    /**
     * @SWG\Property(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $valves_per_cylinder;

    /**
     * @SWG\Property(type="string", maxLength=255)
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $fuel_efficiency;

    /**
     * @SWG\Property(type="string", maxLength=255)
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $max_speed;

    /**
     * @SWG\Property(type="string", maxLength=255)
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $fuel_efficiency_min;

    /**
     * @SWG\Property(type="string", maxLength=255)
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $torque;

    /**
     * @SWG\Property(type="string", maxLength=255)
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $image;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }


    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @return \
     */
    public function setName(string $name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCode()
    {
        return $this->code;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $code
     * @return \
     */
    public function setCode(string $code)
    {
        $this->code = $code;

        return $this;
    }    

    public function getYear()
    {
        return $this->year;
    }

    public function setYear( $year)
    {
        $this->year = $year;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getType()
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    public /**
 * @param $
 */function setType( $type)
    {
        $this->type = $type;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getBodyType()
    {
        return $this->body_type;
    }

    public function setBodyType( $body_type)
    {
        $this->body_type = $body_type;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEnginePower()
    {
        return $this->engine_power;
    }

    public /**
 * @param $
 */function setEnginePower( $engine_power)
    {
        $this->engine_power = $engine_power;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFuel()
    {
        return $this->fuel;
    }

    public /**
 * @param $
 */function setFuel( $fuel)
    {
        $this->fuel = $fuel;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDoors()
    {
        return $this->doors;
    }

    public /**
 * @param $
 */function setDoors( $doors)
    {
        $this->doors = $doors;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSeats()
    {
        return $this->seats;
    }

    public /**
 * @param $
 */function setSeats( $seats)
    {
        $this->seats = $seats;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTransmission()
    {
        return $this->transmission;
    }

    public /**
 * @param $
 */function setTransmission( $transmission)
    {
        $this->transmission = $transmission;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getWeigth()
    {
        return $this->weigth;
    }

    public /**
 * @param $
 */function setWeigth( $weigth)
    {
        $this->weigth = $weigth;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEnginePosition()
    {
        return $this->engine_position;
    }

    public /**
 * @param $
 */function setEnginePosition( $engine_position)
    {
        $this->engine_position = $engine_position;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEngineType()
    {
        return $this->engine_type;
    }

    public /**
 * @param $
 */function setEngineType( $engine_type)
    {
        $this->engine_type = $engine_type;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCylinders()
    {
        return $this->cylinders;
    }

    public /**
 * @param $
 */function setCylinders( $cylinders)
    {
        $this->cylinders = $cylinders;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEngineCapacity()
    {
        return $this->engine_capacity;
    }

    public /**
 * @param $
 */function setEngineCapacity( $engine_capacity)
    {
        $this->engine_capacity = $engine_capacity;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getValvesPerCylinder()
    {
        return $this->valves_per_cylinder;
    }

    public /**
 * @param $
 */function setValvesPerCylinder( $valves_per_cylinder)
    {
        $this->valves_per_cylinder = $valves_per_cylinder;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFuelEfficiency()
    {
        return $this->fuel_efficiency;
    }

    public /**
 * @param $
 */function setFuelEfficiency( $fuel_efficiency)
    {
        $this->fuel_efficiency = $fuel_efficiency;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getMaxSpeed()
    {
        return $this->max_speed;
    }

    public /**
 * @param $
 */function setMaxSpeed( $max_speed)
    {
        $this->max_speed = $max_speed;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFuelEfficiencyMin()
    {
        return $this->fuel_efficiency_min;
    }

    public /**
 * @param $
 */function setFuelEfficiencyMin( $fuel_efficiency_min)
    {
        $this->fuel_efficiency_min = $fuel_efficiency_min;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTorque()
    {
        return $this->torque;
    }

    public /**
 * @param $
 */function setTorque( $torque)
    {
        $this->torque = $torque;

        return $this;
    }

  public function getImage()
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

    public /**
 * @param $
 */function setImage( $image)
    {
        $this->image = $image;

        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getName();
    }
}
```

This is my entity,

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Model\BaseCar;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Swagger\Annotations as SWG;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CarRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity("id")
 */
class Car extends BaseCar
{
   /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Model",cascade={"refresh","merge"}, inversedBy="cars")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    protected $model; 

   public function getModel()
    {
        return $this->model;
    }

    public /**
 * @param $
 */function setModel( $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

But when I use the model I get this error.

> "Property App\Model\BaseCar::$model does not exist"

It would be great help if anyone can answer this.

Comment: Read [Doctrine Inheritance Mapping](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#inheritance-mapping)

Comment: @gp_sflover thanks bro